# Java error regarding object arrays and reading next line from file

Tags: java

I've got a bit of a problem with my java code.
I am trying to create an object array that allows a line of input from a text file.

This is my code:

```
code withheld, solution found
```

That obviously initialises an object array with the size returned from the method.

I try to make a loop that reads each line from the file 'songFile' but returns an error.

Here is my code for the loop:

```
code withheld, solution found
```

This is the code for the getLineAmt method:

```
code withheld, solution found
```

Comment: What error does it "return"?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
 at mainProgram.main(mainProgram.java:23)

Comment: line 23 is the code inside the for loop

Comment: Show us how you initialize songFile??

Comment: Can you post the code for your getLineAmt() method?

Comment: @Francis I have edited my original post with the getLineAmt method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getLineAmt(Scanner songFile)` method is consuming your file when counting the number of lines.  Once the method returns, your `Scanner` has arleady read the file and as reached the end.

One way to solve that is to simply use a `List` object instead of an array, so that you do not need to know the size or your file in advance.

```
List<Song> songList = new ArrayList<Song>();

while(songFile.hasNextLine()) {
    songList.add(new Song(songFile.nextLine()));
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
 
at Song.<init>(Song.java:17)
 
at mainProgram.main(mainProgram.java:22)

Comment: This looks like a problem in your Song constructor.  Have you tested the Song class on it's own to make sure it works?

Comment: I have, I've made a single 'Song' object, and have used just the first line.

The constructor is a string. The string is several characteristics that are split by a comma, and I've used a ".split(",")" function to  get those variables. seeing the error, it seems as though my last split is what is causing the error.....

Comment: Then you may need to validate the data in your "songCollection.txt" file.  Or try running the program in a debugger to see what is going on.  Without the code to Song.java and without the data file, it is hard to say more.

Comment: Thank you for your help Francis. Removing the last "split" seemed to fix the problem. I will try to make a work-around for this. :) 

The ArrayList works, however every single item in the array seems to be data from the last line.... any way to fix this?

Comment: Hard to say without more info.  Are you storing data into static fields in your Song class?  That could explain it.

Comment: Haha that seems to be the issue. Thanks for solving the problem once again! :D

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to read a line without making sure if there are any more lines to be read. You need to modify and add the following check before reading the nextLine

```
for (int i = 0; i < songArray.length; i++)
{
if(songFile.hasNext()){
songArray[i] = new Song(songFile.nextLine());
}
}
```

Comment: this fixes the error, but when trying to read a variable from i.e. songArray[1], it just shows null. same for any other number.

Answer (score 0):

You're counting the lines in the song file, so you are at end of stream, so when you call nextLine() there isn't one. Use an `ArrayList<Song>` instead of an array of `Song[],` then you don't need to count the lines at all.